# How can I increase the thickness of this object without breaking it?

Tags: modifiers, 3d-printing

I'm attempting prepare this object for 3D printing in VeroClear resin. The two halves of the icospheres have been solidified and have a default thickness of 10mil. The objects themselves are scaled to be about 9" on the x- or z-axis. However, I'm aiming for a higher thickness (100mil). When I increase the thickness value in the solidify modifier, the model breaks.

File link: [Star Blender File in Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xlS-P_3P6c2-a3SmMvKXgbW4GA3TdhYu)

Objects with a default thickness in solidify modifier:
[image: Objects with default thickness in solidify modifier]

Objects with thickness updated to 100mil:
[image: Object with thickness updated to 100mil]

Relatively new to Blender and modeling for 3D printing, so I'd really appreciate any suggestions on how to proceed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if this would work, but you might try it (quite possibly with the solidify modifier off, or perhaps only turned off after step 3.) and see if it does:

1. In Edit Mode, select all vertices of an object.
2. Extrude, but don't move the extrusion. Simply click to finalize. This will create
   duplicate vertices, which in this case, you actually want. Duplicating the selection might also work.
3. Lastly, scale up. Only the duplicate vertices should be selected after the extrusion
   operation, so scaling will move them out and create a "shell" of
   sorts.
4. Then add or remove geometry as needed to fill in gaps this
   process might create.

Not gonna lie, if this works it's a bit of a messy solution. Make sure you have a backup save so that if you don't like the results you can revert back.